# Comparison between Data Encryption Tools and Data Sanitization Tools

Tags: php, tools, sql-injection, asp.net, html

> What are the famous Data Sanitization Tools for languages such as ASP/PHP/Html Web Sites?

Which Data Sanitization tools have the best results?

> Difference between Data encryption and Data Sanitization tools with respect to their features? Can we use both tools at the same time?

How can we compare these two Tools?

Comment: Salman, welcome to IT Security!  A warning: I expect this question is likely to be closed, as the question seems to be already answered well by the other question you linked to and the resources linked to from there.  If there is something specific it didn't cover, you'll do better if you make your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, next time I will make more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parametrized query library like SQLi, adodb, or PDO.  If used properly this makes SQL injection impossible.